# Google Recaptcha: Weird graphic glitch?

Tags: recaptcha

I just implemented Google recaptcha on a site and it appears to be having a weird graphic glitch under the box itself.

You can see a picture here:
[image]

As you can see, under the captcha there's some glichy looking lines. Does anyone know a way to get rid of this and or if it's supposed to be there? (I don't think so, but the implementation code is taken directly from google themselves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and figured out that the line height of 20px that I set for the body tag in my CSS file was the culprit. Try this, it worked for me:

```
.recaptchatable * {
  line-height: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to choose a THEME in the implementation of the recaptcha instance on a form building widget for wordpress. It was not indicating ANY theme when it was displaying weird. I seleceted "clean" and it works nice.

[Example](http://www.ake.com/about-us/contact-us/)